# University clubs - Counting two ways

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

> Consider a university with 2000 male and 2000 female students. Suppose that none of the 4000 students signed up for 100 or more clubs (Each student signed up for at most 99 clubs). You also know that each pairing of male,female student shares a club, that they're both signed up for.
>
> Decide if it's possible for every club to have either at most 10 male students or at most 10 female students, or if there must exist at least one club, for which at least 11 male and at least 11 female students signed up.

The general idea I guess would be to count the number of male/female pairs $(2000^2?)$ and then try to get the number of clubs utilizing counting two ways.

I believe that once I get the number of clubs I should be able to verify if it's possible to reach the desired number of pairings with the limitation for male/female students (at most 10 of one or the other). But I'm not sure how to proceed to actually get the number of clubs.

Comment: I think this problem generalizes to $2n^3$ men and $2n^3$ women, with each joining at most $n^2-1$ clubs so that (discarding useless clubs with no men or no women) there can be at most $2n^3(n^2-1)$ clubs. In that case the problem would be to show that some club has at least $n+1$ each of men and women.  At any rate, in the case at hand the number of clubs can't exceed $198,000$ clubs so there must be more than 21 members in some clubs.  But that still leaves the possibility of each such club being unbalanced, such that there are ore than 12 men (women) and fewer than 10 women (men).

Comment: If you slightly weaken the restriction by replacing “at most 99” with “at most 101,” then it is barely possible. That is, it can be done so that every student is in exactly 101 clubs. This suggests that 99 is impossible...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define a club to be men-limited (ML) if it has $\le 10$ men, and women-limited (WL) if it has $\le 10$ women.  (It is possible for a club to be both ML and WL.)  We will prove:

**Claim:** If every club is ML or WL, then some person must join $\ge 100$ clubs.

**Corrollary:** If every person joins $\le 99$ clubs, then some club must be neither ML nor WL.

**Proof of Claim:** Let $J =$ the set of triplets $(m,w,c)$ s.t. $m$ is man, $w$ is a woman, and they both belong to club $c$.  Since each pair of $(m,w)$ has some club in common, there are $\ge 2000^2$ such triplets, i.e. $|J| \ge 2000^2$.

Every club must be either ML or WL, so at least half of the triplets involve clubs which are (without loss of generality) ML.

Now consider a specific woman $w_i$ and all her triplets $(m, w_i, c) \in J$.  Suppose she joined $n_i$ ML clubs.  Since each ML club has $\le 10$ men, such a club can contribute at most $10$ such $(m, w_i, c)$ triplets, so the total no. of triplets involving her and any ML club is $\le 10\, n_i$.

Summing over all women, we have:

$$
\begin{align}
\frac12 \times 2000^2 &\le \text{total no. of triplets involving some ML club} \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^{2000} \text{no. of triplets involving $w_i$ and some ML club}\\
&\le \sum_{i=1}^{2000} 10 \, n_i \\
&\le 2000 \times 10 \times \max_{i=1}^{2000} n_i \\
100 &\le \max_{i=1}^{2000} n_i 
\end{align}
$$

In other words, if at least half of $J$ involve ML clubs, then some woman (e.g. the one with the most ML clubs) must have joined $\ge 100$ ML clubs.  Similarly, if at least half of $J$ involve WL clubs, then some man must have joined $\ge 100$ WL clubs.  Since every club is ML or WL, at least one of the two cases must happen.  QED

---

**Stronger Claim:** In fact, the necessary and sufficient upperbound (on number of clubs joined by any person) is $101$ (not $100$).

Necessity: Continuing from above, some woman must join $\ge 100$ ML clubs.  If she has joined exactly $100$ ML clubs and no WL club, however, those only contribute $100 \times 10 = 1000$ different $(m,w,c)$ triplets, which is fewer than the $2000$ triplets involving her.  So she must have joined either $> 100$ ML clubs, or $100$ ML clubs and $>1$ WL club.  Thus her total no. of clubs $\ge 101$.

Sufficiency: Consider the $2000$ men partitioned into $200$ packs of $10$ each, and same for the women.  Everybody in the same pack will join the same clubs.  An ML (resp. WL) club will have exactly $1$ pack of $10$ men (resp. women).  Who joins what club can be represented by a $200\times 200$ matrix.  Here is an explicit construction where the numbers show club ID.  The horizontal and vertical dividers divide the $200\times 200$ matrix into four $100\times 100$ blocks, and are just for ease of viewing.

```
  1    2   ...   99  100 | 101  101  ...  101  101
  1    2   ...   99  100 | 102  102  ...  102  102
  .    .         .    .  |  .    .         .    .
  .    .         .    .  |  .    .         .    .
  1    2   ...   99  100 | 199  199  ...  199  199
  1    2   ...   99  100 | 200  200  ...  200  200
 ------------------------+------------------------
 201  201  ...  201  201 | 301  302  ...  399  400
 202  202  ...  202  202 | 301  302  ...  399  400
  .    .         .    .  |  .    .         .    .
  .    .         .    .  |  .    .         .    .
 299  299  ...  299  299 | 301  302  ...  399  400
 300  300  ...  300  300 | 301  302  ...  399  400
```

It is easy to verify that (a) each club ID appears in either one column or one row (either ML or WL), and (b) each row/column (each man/woman pack) contains only $101$ different club IDs.

Answer (score 1):

To minimize the number of members in clubs, assume that for any man-woman pairing, there exists only for one club that has both of them as members.

Define the matrix with elements $C_{mw}$ being the club id that has man $m$ and women $w$ both as members. All elements of the matrix need to be filled, and the question asks whether the number of different ids in any row or column can be less than 100 when the number of men or women in all clubs is 10 or less.

Without loss of generality, we can populate the upper 10 rows of the matrix with club id = 1. There are 10 men and 2000 women in club #1. There is no benefit in breaking that block into 2 or more clubs.

If we continue and populate the next 10 rows with club id = 2, and repeat, then the women will all belong to 200 clubs, violating the requirement. Instead, the leftmost 10 columns could be filled with club id=2, corresponding to 10 women and 2000 men.

With both, the upper left block of 10x10 has man-woman pairing for two clubs. We can eliminate one of the clubs. The most sparse solution (reducing number of clubs everyone belongs to) leaves a checker-board pattern for the matrix.

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 & 1 & 2 & 1 & 2 & 1 & 2 & 1 & 2 & 1 & 4 &  ... \\
2 & 1 & 2 & 1 & 2 & 1 & 2 & 1 & 2 & 1 & 2 & 1 &  ... \\
1 & 2 & 1 & 2 & 1 & 2 & 1 & 2 & 1 & 2 & 1 & 4 &  ... \\
2 & 1 & 2 & 1 & 2 & 1 & 2 & 1 & 2 & 1 & 2 & 1 &  ... \\
1 & 2 & 1 & 2 & 1 & 2 & 1 & 2 & 1 & 2 & 1 & 4 &  ... \\
2 & 1 & 2 & 1 & 2 & 1 & 2 & 1 & 2 & 1 & 2 & 1 &  ... \\
1 & 2 & 1 & 2 & 1 & 2 & 1 & 2 & 1 & 2 & 1 & 4 &  ... \\
2 & 1 & 2 & 1 & 2 & 1 & 2 & 1 & 2 & 1 & 2 & 1 &  ... \\
1 & 2 & 1 & 2 & 1 & 2 & 1 & 2 & 1 & 2 & 1 & 4 &  ... \\
2 & 1 & 2 & 1 & 2 & 1 & 2 & 1 & 2 & 1 & 2 & 1 &  ... \\
3 & 2 & 3 & 2 & 3 & 2 & 3 & 2 & 3 & 2 & 3 & 4 &  ... \\
2 & 3 & 2 & 3 & 2 & 3 & 2 & 3 & 2 & 3 & 2 & 3 &  ... \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

This is a solution in which every club has either 10 men and 1000 women or 10 women and 1000 men and everyone belongs to 100 clubs. It does not appear that there would be a solution where everyone belongs to at most 99 clubs.

Comment: I don't think I understand your notation.  Take the top-left $2\times 2$ block: Since $C_{11}=C_{22} = 1$, this means both men and both women belong to club id $1$.  But since $C_{12}=C_{21} = 2$, this also means both men and both women belong to club id $2$.  Doesn't this then violate your assumption of there being only one club for every pairing?

Comment: Good point! My first assumption was made so that the matrix elements only have one value, but as you correctly pointed out, it does not ensure that there is only one club for each pairing.